# When the item is added, the drag event does not work

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

drag and drop eventim works but I can't run it with the buttons I added.
I know I should run as on click, but I didn't get any results.
Can you help? Thanks ...

https://codepen.io/celilsahin/pen/BqGvLm

```
<ul class="handles list">
<li class="red"><span>::</span></li>
<li class="purple"><span>::</span></li>
<li class="orange"><span>::</span></li>
<li class="yellow"><span>::</span></li>
<li class="blue"><span>::</span></li>
</ul>

<button>Add</button>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.sortable.js"></script> 
<script>
$(function(){
$('.handles').sortable({
handle: 'span'
});

("button").click(function(){
$( ".handles" ).append($('<li class="red"><span>::</span></li>').hide().fadeIn(300));
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+sortable+dynamically+added) finds lots of questions about using jQuery UI Sortable with dynamically-added elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it adding $('.handles').sortable('refresh'); in code

$("button").click(function(){
      $( ".handles" ).append($('::').hide().fadeIn(300));
      $('.handles').sortable('refresh');
    });